# Data Not Showing up in Table

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to follow a example of creating a table located here:
https://pythonbasics.org/pyqt-table/

Full admission, I am new to python and this is a little foreign to me.

I have edited my dictionary to match my data, but when the table is populated on my computer, the values are blank.

I am at a loss of where I went wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code snips below:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)  
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
x = []
labels = []
for i in range(sheet.nrows-3): 
   print(sheet.row_values(i+3)) 
   x.append(sheet.row_values(i+3))
   labels.append(str(x[i][0])+" "+str(x[i][1]))


z={}
keypieces = range(len(x))
#Making the Z dictionary
for i in keypieces: 
    z[labels[i]] = x[i][4:7]

class TableView(QTableWidget):
def __init__(self, z, *args):
    QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
    self.z = z
    self.setz()
    self.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.resizeRowsToContents()

def setz(self): 
    horHeaders = []
    for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.z.keys())):
        horHeaders.append(key)
        for m, item in enumerate(self.z[key]):
            newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
            self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
    self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    table = TableView(z, 3, 6)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

My z dictionary is the following:

```
{'LEVEL 6 S1': [24.4999999999989, 5.00000000000394, 1.5],
 'LEVEL 5 S1': [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.5],
 'LEVEL 4 S1': [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.5],
 'LEVEL 3 S1': [25.4999999999992, 3.41666666666662, 1.5],
 'LEVEL 2 S1': [25.4999999999992, 3.91666666666663, 3.0],
 'LEVEL 1 S1': [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.33333333333333]}
```

My table looks like this (red is one example of what I want the table to look like):

[image: Table image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error is that QTableWidgetItem supports only string, on the other hand the method you use to access the information is redundant. They consider the above the solution is:

```py
def setz(self):
    horHeaders = []
    for j, (key, values) in enumerate(sorted(self.z.items())):
        horHeaders.append(key)
        for i, value in enumerate(values):
            newitem = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
            # or
            # newitem = QTableWidgetItem()
            # newitem.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, value)
            self.setItem(i, j, newitem)
    self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to support numerical values and strings you must use the roles (Qt::DisplayRole or Qt::UserRole):

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class TableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, z, *args):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(*args)
        self.z = z
        self.setz()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def setz(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for j, (key, values) in enumerate(sorted(self.z.items())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem()
                newitem.setData(Qt.EditRole, value)
                self.setItem(i, j, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)


def main(args):

    z = {
        "LEVEL 6 S1": [24.4999999999989, 5.00000000000394, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 5 S1": [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 4 S1": [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 3 S1": [25.4999999999992, 3.41666666666662, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 2 S1": [25.4999999999992, 3.91666666666663, 3.0],
        "LEVEL 1 S1": [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.33333333333333],
    }

    app = QApplication(args)
    table = TableView(z, 3, 6)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

If instead you want to force all created columns to support floating values by default then you must set an appropriate editor, such as the QDoubleSpinBox, in the delegate

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDoubleSpinBox,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QTableWidget,
    QTableWidgetItem,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        DBL_MAX = 1.7976931348623157e308
        editor = QDoubleSpinBox(parent, minimum=-DBL_MAX, maximum=DBL_MAX, decimals=323)
        return editor


class TableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, z, *args):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(*args)
        self.z = z
        self.setz()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

        delegate = Delegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    def setz(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for j, (key, values) in enumerate(sorted(self.z.items())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem()
                newitem.setData(Qt.EditRole, value)
                self.setItem(i, j, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)


def main(args):

    z = {
        "LEVEL 6 S1": [24.4999999999989, 5.00000000000394, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 5 S1": [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 4 S1": [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 3 S1": [25.4999999999992, 3.41666666666662, 1.5],
        "LEVEL 2 S1": [25.4999999999992, 3.91666666666663, 3.0],
        "LEVEL 1 S1": [25.4999999999992, 4.99999999999996, 1.33333333333333],
    }

    app = QApplication(args)
    table = TableView(z, 3, 6)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thank you eylllanesc. My end goal here is that I want to add add an additional row below row 3 and have it prompt a user for numerical input. Not sure if I like the idea of only being able to accept strings. Do you know if tkinter works better at accepting numbers and integers vs pyqt?  I also need to research how to interact with user input data after the form is filled out.

Comment: @Retug 1) Do you want all items to support numerical values? 2) The choice between tkinter and pyqt is very subjective since both have the same potential but in a different way, so I will not answer this question.

Comment: I would love to support both strings and numerical values (even tell the user that they input wrong data if i expected a string and was provided a number).

Comment: thanks. do you have much experience in taking user input from a form and doing more work on the user input (like I had mentioned in my earlier post of wanting to add a blank row 4)? the few examples I have seen are written from pyqt4 times and would love a good example of prompting the user for input in a form and then doing more work within the code on that user input data.

Comment: @Retug 1) The questions should not be referred to people's ability as it is irrelevant to SO so I will avoid answering that question. 2) That new row what type of data should allow: string or floats ?, a form restricts the user what type of data should provide so you must clearly indicate what type of data that new row should have. 3) On the other hand many of the things that are compatible between PyQt4 and PyQt5, you should also check the Q/A of SO since there are thousands of examples.

Comment: @elyannsc, 1) apologies. 2) supporting strings. 3) I will do more research.